# How to make random choose from a set in Python reproducible

Tags: python-3.x, set

I wrote a simple sample code here. In fact, elements will be added or deleted from the set and a random element will be chosen from the set on each iteration in my program.

But even if I run the simplified code below, I got different output every time I run the codes. So, how to make the outputs reproducible?

```
import random
random.seed(0)
x = set()
for i in range(40):
    x.add('a'+str(i))
print(random.sample(x, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a set's elements are unordered, and will vary between runs even if the random sample chooses the same thing. Using `random.sample` on a set is in fact [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) since python 3.9, and in the future you will need to input a sequence instead.

You could do this by converting the set to a sequence in a consistently ordered way, such as

```py
x = sorted(x)
```

or probably better, just use a type like `list` in the first place (always producing `['a24']` in your example).

```py
x = ['a' + str(i) for i in range(40)]
```